# Changing the name of the committer in Xcode

Tags: xcode, git

i am working with an other developer in developing an iOS application and now he don't work with us and i am working with his computer but the problem is when i push my code i am seeing his name appearing in the github. how i can change this and put my name appearing in the github. thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a .gitconfig file in your project directory, if so, `cd` into the project directory and run the following commands to set it to your name and email in the .gitconfig file of your project

```
git config user.name "Your Name"
git config user.email "your-email-address@email.com"
```

If you do not have a .gitconfig file in your project directory, it could be using the global .gitconfig file located in the Home directory (`~/`). Simply add the `--global` flag to set it on a global basis for all projects (note, if there is a .gitconfig file within the project directory, it will use that rather than the global .gitconfig in the home directory)

```
git config --global user.name "Your name"
git config --global user.email "your-email-address@email.com"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it helped me to resolve this. i have done the same think in the command line : git config --global user.email xxx@fff.ffr
git config --global user.name "User name"